# How are atomic bonds created?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-chemistry

From what I have learned in my chemistry course, Electrons with similar quantum numbers but with opposite spin are attracted to each other. What does this mean when there is a covalent bond being formed between lets say hydrogen and fluorine?

I can think of four different results:

A) A bond is not formed until an unpaired fluorine electron meets an unpaired hydrogen electron with the same energy shift (in this case, 0).

B) The fluorine or hydrogen electron forces the other electron to have the same energy shift.

C) The electrons don't change, but pair up regardless of quantum numbers.

D) The electrons from both atoms enter into a different state that I have not learned yet.

Thanks in advance for any help received!

Comment: chemistry stackexchange?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ is maybe a better place for your question ?

Comment: [Chemistry.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chemistry and physics have a lot of overlaps. This could be atomic physics too...

I don't have a short explanation, but look up [orbital hybridization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation) and [molecular orbital theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory) for a quantum-mechanical view of this.

The above two should point you in a promising direction.

Good luck with understanding the physics of bonding.